# Calling Save() after findAll() in JPA repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on an SpringBoot Project and Using the Spring JPA.
I have scenario where I need to fetch all the records and then update them after modification.
For example

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="Employee")
 public class Employee{
   
   @ID
   @Column(name="ID")
   Long id;

   @Column(name="age")
   private  int age;
   
   @Column(name="name")
   private  String name;

   @Embedded
   private Address address

   //TODO getters and setters goes below
 }
```

and then in the repository

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JPARepository<Employee, Long>{
}
```

and in the service Iam trying as below:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService{
 
  @Autowired
  EmployeeRepository repository;

 @Transactional
 public void updateEmployee(){
     List<Employee> list = repository.findAll();
     for(Employee employee :list) {

      employee.setAge(employee.getAge()+4);
     
      repository.save(employee); //This is not working.
     }
  }
}
```

Save is neither working nor throwing any error.I have also tried saveAndFlush() but not working. Can someone please help me. I want my objects to get updated.

Comment: What's the @Embedded Address for? Is it grouping of columns? And can you post the generated query? Set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see it in the logs.

Comment: Are you sure you get the list of employees on line: `List<Employee> list = repository.findAll();`?

Comment: @Ayush28 Yes. Iam able to see the list of employees

Comment: @George, I dont get any sql generated during save operation. It seems the query is not even getting fired. It is like Nothing happened. Where as in the list there are multiple records.

Comment: @VinayPandey Have you enabled the JPA repositories?

Comment: @Ayush28, Yes Without it i would not even get the list of employees. Is there something else you are pointing to.

Comment: Try annotating your application file(one with main method) with `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"your.base.package"})`.

Comment: Haven't tried to reproduce your example but I would suspect the @Transactional annotation over there since you are trying to make both happen within the same transaction.

Comment: @eray what is the problem with Transactional annotation. I have other things to do in between, that's why I have added the transactional.

Comment: @Ayush28 EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"your.base.package"}) is already present in DatabaseConfig configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your issue, but i cant reproduce your error.

[image: Tried to replicate your issue here]

My entities get updated with this perfectly fine.

[image: After updates]

You say you are doing more logic than this, have you tried printing out your entities after you have made the save, to see if something has been updated, and that it fails in another place in your code?

The code above for me updates all entities as expected :)

---

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
```

Add this to application.properties / yaml file for more tracing of SQL statements

Comment: I cannot use saveAll because there is some more code after that. I just want obects to be updated one by one. Also, If save() is not working how come saveAll is supposed to work.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but it works fine for me, so there must be something else wrong :) can you share more code?

Comment: Maybe changing logging level to debug could help you see what's happening behind the doors.

Comment: Yes, by adding "logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE" to your application.properties/yaml file you will be able to see what is happening behind the scenes :)

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to help me. It is working fine, It was my mistake, I was able to see the data in the tables after the transaction was completed. And also I was initially testing it with unit tests so everything changed was getting rolled back after test completion and i was keep getting confused. Apologies .